# Android: custom draw on an given image (with SurfaceView)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to load an image to SurfaceView, and draw some scratch upon this image.

To to that, I have create an custom SurfaceView, MySurfaceView, with the following functions:

```
public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mBitmap = bitmap;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, null);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }
    if (mPath != null) {
        Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
```

Basically if keep **setWillNotDraw(false)** in the constructor, the SurfaceView will show the bitmap that I set **mBitmap**. Otherwise, if I comment this out, it will allow me to draw paths on a black background.

Is there any way that I can do both, put image (mBitmap) in the background and draw paths on this image? Could you guys provide some code to do that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've got your rendering code in two different places.  Do all of your drawing, both bitmap and path, in onDraw().  Initiate the draw by sending an invalidate event to the View.

Comment: Thanks! How can I draw path in onDraw? I thought that drawing path has to be triggered by onTouchEvent(), right?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

It is basically put the draw path to **onDraw(Canvas canvas)** function as well. To make sure the SurfaceView call onDraw once a path is drew. We need to call **invalidate()** in on touch event.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapScaled, x, y, null);
    if (mPath != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Or even better, you can change the mPath into an ArrayList, so that you can put more paths on the image.