# Save image on Canvas to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

How can I save the image on a canvas to bitmap? 
There are several related posts, but I didn't find the one works for me. To make it clear, here is my problem

What's on my canvas:

1. An bitmap image which was drawn to the canvas using **canvas.drawBitmap**(oldBitmap, x, y, null);
2. Some paths drawn overlay to this image on the same canvas using **canvas.drawPath**.

Both the image and the paths are draw on a customized SurfaceView. And both they are draw to the canvas in the **onDraw** function. Or more specific, the implementation is in the following link:

[Android: custom draw on an given image (with SurfaceView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194026/android-custom-draw-on-an-given-image-with-surfaceview)

Now I need to save the image on canvas (the oldBitmap and paths I drew) to a newBitmap. Could someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to retrieve a Bitmap from a Canvas. One way to do this, though, is to create a member Bitmap object that isn't shown on-screen, create a Canvas for it, and mirror all the drawing operations on that.

Comment: Thank you! I see, but how can I mirror the drawPath operations?

Comment: When you call `canvas.drawPath()`, call `myCanvas.drawPath()` with the same Path and Paint objects, where `myCanvas` is as I described in the previous comment.

Comment: You can get a bitmap from a canvas using the getDrawingCache() method.

Comment: @DeveloperPaul I don't think that works consistently, if at all, with a SurfaceView.

Comment: You're probably right